# What is the logic in using standard error while working with median?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I have data from sessions that contain time responses of mice to stimuli.
The data contains extreme values since sometimes the mouse decides to "take a break" so I have to use median statistics.

So, I took out extreme values Matlabs outlier removal function.

Now I want to analyse the error in which session.

I have seen that people do it usin standard error of the mean which is, to my (little) knowledge:

$$ SEM = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n} = \frac {{\sqrt{\sum (x_i-\overline x)^2}} \cdot {\frac{1}{\sqrt {n-1}}}}{\sqrt n} $$ (am I right?)

my question is:

> What is the logic in using the mean here if we do our analysis using median (assuming mean is not indicative enough)?
>   Also, are there any other error analysis methods that can fit here? (using IQR gives to big range and therefore not indicative enough..)

Thanks!

Comment: The whole world of quantile regression sounds relevant here??????

Comment: @PaulHewson, If I knew what it is then maybe it would sound relevant..:) My problem is that, if there are "outsider" values that diverse the mean and therefore "ruin" it , they should also diverse the standard deviation and therefore "ruin" it too.. if there is a way to explain what is quantile regression and why the problem don't exist there I would be greatful to hear it.. anyways.. Thanks!

Comment: There's a brief intro to quantile regression here: https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-quantile-regression/

Comment: The alternatives include robust regression. https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Robust_Regression.pdf

Comment: I've never used it myself but Matlab has a robust regression toolbox: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/robustfit.html

Comment: I think the difference is that in quantile regression, you would explicitly focus on the median (50th percentile) or any other percentile.   In robust regression, you are looking for something more akin to conditional means, but you downweight the outliers.   I said quantile regression because you said median, but it might be that robust regression toolkit is more what you want.   And ANOVA (y ~ x) where x is a group membership (treatment or control) is "just" a regression problem.

Comment: @PaulHewson, OK will look it up. Thanks!